# NumericMatrix not recognized as a type in RcppParallel Package

Tags: c++, r, parallel-processing, rcpp, r-package

I'm learning to use RcppParallel to use in my work and was trying to install a simple package made with Rcpp.package.skeleton(). The package contains three source files, the Rcpp's HelloWorld (rcpp_hello_world.cpp) and the two versions of the matrix transformation functions found in the RcppParallel website (http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/parallel-matrix-transform/). The serial version (matrixSqrt.cpp) and a the parallel version (parallelMatrixSqrt.cpp). Also, I made the necessary additions to the DESCRIPTION and NAMESPACE files, and made the Makevars and Makevars.win with the suggested lines.

The problem is, when I try to install the package, i got the following error:

> parallelMatrixSqrt.cpp:14:21: error: ‘NumericMatrix’ does not name a type
>       SquareRoot(const NumericMatrix input, NumericMatrix output)

I don't know if it is a linker problem. The Makevars files looks like this:

Makevars

```
PKG_LIBS += $(shell ${R_HOME}/bin/Rscript -e "RcppParallel::RcppParallelLibs()")
```

Makevars.win

```
PKG_CXXFLAGS += -DRCPP_PARALLEL_USE_TBB=1
PKG_LIBS += $(shell "${R_HOME}/bin${R_ARCH_BIN}/Rscript.exe" \
              -e "RcppParallel::RcppParallelLibs()")
```

EDIT:
This is how the parallelMatrixSqrt.cpp looks like

```
#include <RcppParallel.h>
using namespace RcppParallel;

struct SquareRoot : public Worker
{
   // source matrix
   const RMatrix<double> input;

   // destination matrix
   RMatrix<double> output;

   // initialize with source and destination
   SquareRoot(const NumericMatrix input, NumericMatrix output) 
      : input(input), output(output) {}

   // take the square root of the range of elements requested
   void operator()(std::size_t begin, std::size_t end) {
      std::transform(input.begin() + begin, 
                     input.begin() + end, 
                     output.begin() + begin, 
                     ::sqrt);
   }
};

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericMatrix parallelMatrixSqrt(NumericMatrix x) {

  // allocate the output matrix
  NumericMatrix output(x.nrow(), x.ncol());

  // SquareRoot functor (pass input and output matrixes)
  SquareRoot squareRoot(x, output);

  // call parallelFor to do the work
  parallelFor(0, x.length(), squareRoot);

  // return the output matrix
  return output;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: That's not a linker error. Linker wouldn't complain about a missing type. Those are picked off by the compiler. Odds are good you 1. Have the dreaded Typo! 2. Are missing a header,  or 3. Have a circular dependency in your headers. Need to see code to do anything more than guess.

Comment: Prefix it: `Rcpp::NumericMatrix`, or use `using namespace Rcpp`.  Look more closely at what the working examples do.

Comment: I'm using the code they provide, so I use "using namespace RcppParallel". In the documentation, they say to never make reference to the R or Rcpp API while using threaded (RcppParallel) code, so I don't think I should use the Rcpp:: prefix.

Comment: "They" don't use `NumericMatrix` objects.  My advice still stands.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `NumericMatrix` class is provided by `Rcpp`, so you need to access it either by pulling in the Rcpp namespace with

```
using namespace Rcpp;
```

or explicitly prefix the namespace name, e.g.

```
Rcpp::NumericMatrix
```

Note that the warning re: avoiding use of the R / Rcpp API implies avoiding their use within the definition of your `RcppParallel::Worker` functions. The over-arching reason you want to avoid using the R / Rcpp API within a parallel context is that these routines may:

1. Allocate, and hence trigger the R garbage collector, which will cause big problems if done on a separate thread; or
2. Throw an error, and hence cause a `longjmp` that blows up the universe (which, if I understand correctly, is a permissible consequence of undefined behavior in a C++ program)

You can typically construct your `Worker` object from `Rcpp` objects, but to be safe you generally want to store the associated data with a local `RcppParallel::RMatrix<T>` object, as that object is 'safer' in that it only provides routines that are safe to use in a parallel context -- in particular, it provides iterators that allow you to use it with the C++ STL, which should be sufficient in many scenarios.

Comment: Thanks, Kevin.
So, I can use the Rcpp API in the constructor because those objects aren't used to perform calculations? Like, just as containers for the input data, and then the data to be returned?

With the prefix it works now (as you and Dirk told me), thanks. The thing is, the documentation is not so clear about the used of both Rcpp and RcppParallel, at least for me, that have been using R for less than 3 months.

Comment: I agree this could be better documented, but the overarching idea is -- for code that could be run in parallel / on multiple threads, don't call into the R or Rcpp APIs, unless you know it's a threadsafe API.

In general, that means the `operator()` implementations, and the `join` implementations, for `RcppParallel::Worker`s.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <RcppParallel.h>
using namespace RcppParallel;
```

**Patch your code with the below lines instead of the above lines in your code. You haven't included the Rcpp name space and this worked for me.**

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppParallel)]]
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <RcppParallel.h>
using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace RcppParallel;
```

You haven't pulled the Rcpp namespace, that will be needed during the compilation of the space NumericVector or NumericMatrix.

**So, the working code will be**

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppParallel)]]
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <RcppParallel.h>
#include <limits>
using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace RcppParallel;
struct SquareRoot : public Worker
{
// source matrix
 const RMatrix<double> input;

// destination matrix
RMatrix<double> output;

// initialize with source and destination
 SquareRoot(const NumericMatrix input, NumericMatrix output) 
 : input(input), output(output) {}

// take the square root of the range of elements requested
 void operator()(std::size_t begin, std::size_t end) {
 std::transform(input.begin() + begin, 
               input.begin() + end, 
               output.begin() + begin, 
               ::sqrt);
 }
 };

  // [[Rcpp::export]]
   NumericMatrix parallelMatrixSqrt(NumericMatrix x) {

  // allocate the output matrix
   NumericMatrix output(x.nrow(), x.ncol());

  // SquareRoot functor (pass input and output matrixes)
   SquareRoot squareRoot(x, output);

  // call parallelFor to do the work
    parallelFor(0, x.length(), squareRoot);

  // return the output matrix
  return output;
  }
```

However, I get the error for "no matching function to call for transform", If you know the answer may be, kindly reply.